# Can my cousin copyright his world population cartogram?

Tags: copyright, maps

My cousin made a cartogram depicting world population in microsoft paint.

[image: ]()![world population cartogram]

It became [quite popular](http://www.npr.org/blogs/goatsandsoda/2015/01/28/381971608/india-grows-russia-shrinks-mapping-countries-by-population) and he he was contacted by the author of an earlier world population cartogram.

[image]

The author of the early cartogram insisted that my cousin's work violated his copyright. My cousin acquiesced and listed the earlier author as the copyright holder of the newer map.

It seems wrong to me.  My cousin's work seems original.  But the lawyer at his university said that it is not.  Who is right?

Comment: Too bad. Do you know any good forums for copyright questions?

Comment: No, I don't know of any sites in the Stack Exchange network that would be able to help with this, off-hand. There's an [Area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66416/intellectual-property?referrer=PGb8oLMzIQXaMXtO_GVaIw2) in the works for Intellectual Property questions, but that of course won't work right now. [graphicdesign.se] comes to mind as a *maybe*, but you'd have to check with their help center.

Comment: Thanks I did end up posting in Graphic Design. I also followed the area 51 proposal. Should I do anything with this post (delete?) or can I just leave it hear on a wish and a prayer?

Comment: We can leave this here for now. The Community user will delete it in a week or two, but for now I'll keep thinking of a better site for it, in case Graphic Design doesn't keep it.

Comment: One possible solution would be to find earlier versions of world population cartograms to 'push back' against the person claiming copyright. Try looking up cartogram references from John Snyder's [Bibliography of Map Projections](http://www.csiss.org/map-projections/Reference/Bull1856.pdf).